# Circular Clothoid Curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, differential

One clothoid curve (see figure) has the curve parameters $(C^2= 9$ x $10^8 m^2, L= 315m)$. The starting point A of this curve is the beginning point of a road. The coordinates of point A are $(2000.000, 5200.000)$. The azimuth of the tangent of this curve at point A is $120^o$. A circular curve follows this clothoid. Please calculate the following questions.

(a) The radius of the circular curve.

(b) The coordinates of the point at the clothoid arc length $40m$ from the point A.

(c) The coordinates of the end point of the clothoid.

(d) The coordinates of the point where the length of the road from the beginning is $340m$. This point is located on the circular curve.

[image]

What I have calculated for parts (a) and (b) are below. I need help with parts (c) and (d). Thanks in advance.

If the image is not clear, my answers are (a) $R=2.86$ x $10^6m$ and for (b) $x=2000.3556, y=1200074.998$

[image]

Comment: Isn't $L$ the total length of the curve? If so, part (c) is the same as part (b), with 315 replacing 40.